# Is there a reason why certain verbs use certain cases?

Tags: semantics, grammar, verbs, cases

For examples, in German there are certain verbs that always use the dative cases and others that always use the accusative case. Is there a logical or semantical reason for this?

Does the use of a certain case alter the way speakers of the language perceive or interpret the meaning of the verb/sentence? For examples, say we have two languages (A and B) and a verb (X). If language A uses the accusative case with verb X, but language B uses the dative (why would they do in the first place? Shouldn’t the meaning of some verbs be UNIVERSAL?), will this in turn result in that speakers of language A will have a slightly different notion of verb X than those of language B, even if the general idea behind the verb is the same for both speakers?

Comment: In German, there are also verbs that take the genitive, like *bedürfen* or *sich erfreuen"

Comment: An average speaker of any language has not a slightest idea about all of those cases, governings and alignments of yours, they just speak their language and that's all. Could you possibly suggest a way in which the idea of “I thank you” in, say, German, where _danken_ needs a dative object, can be different from that of, say, Russian, where the the corresponding verb _благодарить_ needs accusative, and from English where _thank_ needs an objective pronoun? What kind of technique would you use to establish if there is a difference or those three verbs mean exactly the same?

Comment: I vote to close this question as opinion-based unless it is reformulated to fit the framework of this SE.

Comment: This is interesting to ponder, but I don’t think it’s possible to answer in generic terms. Each case would have to be evaluated within the specific framework of what logic governs how an individual language uses the cases it has as its disposal, because meanings of verbs are emphatically **not** universal. Even then, it’s not always clear-cut – for example, Icelandic _spúa_ and _æla_ both mean ‘to vomit’, but _spúa_ takes the dative and _æla_ takes the accusative. And it’s almost impossible to know for sure if two speakers have exactly the same notion of a verb, even within the same language.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet “Icelandic spúa and æla both mean ‘to vomit’, but spúa takes the dative and æla takes the accusative” — In fact, both verbs take the dative. See, for example, Cleasby and Vigfusson “***æla***, … 2. _to throw up, vomit;_ æla öllu upp”, and in 1907 poet and editor Jónas Guðlaugsson wrote (concerning Danish opposition to the idea of creating an Icelandic national flag): “… sjálfum frelsisgarpinum Brandes … varð svo bumbult af þessu, að hann ældi Amagerkáli út um alla Höfn.”

Comment: Declensions are not necessarily linked to verbs. But even so, how can a verb in one language be expected to mean the same in another? Each language has its own logic.

Comment: @Segorian Huh, I always thought it took the accusative, but some sample searches confirms that it does take the dative. I recall my old Icelandic teacher giving a few examples of pairs of more or less synonymous verbs that take different cases, and _æla_ was the one I could remember, but it seems I misremembered. I also thought he mentioned a pair meaning something like ‘throw’ or ‘kick’, but all the words I can find for those actions also take the dative. I’m sure there were some actual examples, though!

Comment: If you are only discussing German, that should be in the title of the question.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Yes, words for ‘throw’ or ‘kick’ all seem to take the dative. However, a throw is a kind of move, and of the many verbs with the meaning ‘to move’ (either in general or in a specific way), _flytja_ and _færa_ take the accusative, while _hliðra, hnika, mjaka, muna, skjóta, ýta_ and _þoka_ take the dative. Further, _aka_, which can mean ‘to drive’, ‘to move’ or ‘to transport’ (in a vehicle), has historically taken both cases. Today, _aka veginn_ (acc.) is ‘to drive the road’, while _aka bílnum_ (dat.) is ‘to drive the car’. _continued in next comment_

Comment: _cont’d._ 
Finally, keyra, which also means ‘to drive’, normally takes the accusative, but when the meaning is, for example, ‘to drive someone home’, the dative is sometimes heard (although most people consider that usage non-standard).

Answer (score 2):

Cases, like prepositions, are somewhat **arbitrary**.

One proof of this is that they vary within a language and over time.

> will this in turn result in that speakers of language A will have a slightly different notion of verb X

Maybe we could find examples where the notion is linked to case, and case is actually the cause and not just an effect.

But people overwhelmingly just don’t think about cases, prepositions, tenses, grammatical gender, auxiliary verbs etc of their native languages.

Comment: Relevant but niche joke: 
`Warum schneide d Preisse in de Prifinge immer so schlecht ab?  Weil se *zur* Schul gehe, aber net *in* d Schul.`